# Access UCM Content from backend

Tags: oracle, backend, oracle-ucm

Is there any way to get and process the UCM content from a Java class? What I need is to sort a content list based on the metadata field. I can get it from a `.jsff` page. But I need to iterate `dt:contentListTemplateDef` with that sorted list. Any information will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into RIDC? The *Remote IDC* is available for both 10g and 11G UCM. It allows you to call upon (almost) every service available in UCM from within your custom java application, including searching, sorting, ...

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e16819/toc.htm) for the 11g documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Wivani. Can you give me some references from where I can learn how use this RIDC api? I read those documentation but I need to know more like getting metadata information or getting the list of the content type available in UCM etc.

Comment: Personally I've had the chance to learn this at Oracle University (employer paid). It involves wrapping your head about the design of UCM and its use of services all over the place; the hda file-format and htm-tables and so on. I've never found very good documentation about this on the net but there is the book by Brian Huff _Stellent Content Server Development_ which is even a few versions later still a good guide.

Comment: I have links to many RIDC examples on my blog: http://jonathanhult.com/blog/2012/12/ridc-examples/

Comment: Seems like a great resource. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to return any query as an RSS feed, JSON or XML.